# if...else jsp mysql color boxes

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, if-statement

I am making 2*2 matrix. 
I am getting coordinates like x=0,y=1 and x=1, y=0 from my db.

I want to check if the expiry date is about to finish or not.. If it is about to finish then change the color of the box in that particular coordinate.

Please help me.
I wrote the code but its not working in "JSP and HTML".

```jsp
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>

//creating a table
<table style="width: 272px; height: 282px; " align="center" frame="border" title="X,Y Coordinates">
  <tr>


  <%

String inbounddate = request.getParameter("ExpiryDate");
String expirydt = request.getParameter("ExpiryDate");
String Ycord = request.getParameter("ycoordinate");
String Xcord = request.getParameter("ycoordinate");

java.sql.Connection conf = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz","root","root"); 
Statement sqlt= conf.createStatement(); 

  ResultSet res=st.executeQuery("select * from proj'"+expirydt+"'"+inbounddate+""); 

<%
if (expirydt > inbounddate)
{
 if (Xcord ==1 && Ycord ==2)

{
//color box 2nd box
 <th align="center" bgcolor="" axis="1,2" scope="row" bordercolor="#0000"></th>
}
else
{
 <th align="center" bgcolor="" axis="0,0" scope="row" bordercolor="#1010"></th>
}
}
else
{
...
}

%>
```

I know its wrong, I am a naive. 
please help me.

Comment: Your code is misaligned and thus hard to read. -1 for not making the minimal effort of aligning code in a readable way

Comment: What cant you read??!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare twos strings with `.equals` instead of `==` operator. Your `if` statment should be like below

```
   if ("1".equals(Xcord) && "2".equals(Ycord)){
}
```

Or you have to parse the `String` as `int` using `Integer.parseInt` and then you have to compare it.

To debug your code use the `out.println` method like `out.println("The value of xcord is >> "+Xcord)` command to print the values in the jsp and check whether all the values are fetched properly, this will save your time